# Vertical progress bar in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I need a veritical progress bar in swing to display a temperature in one case and a voltage in another. How can I accomplish this?

Can I set the progress bar to a vertical mode?

Can I use the slider control in a read only mode in which it id not adjustable? I was thinking I could simply set the slider to the actual value when the user attempted to modify it but that seems clunky.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you see when you looked in the JavaDocs: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html? And when you tried constructing it with vertical orientation, what happened?

Comment: I have to agree with kdgregory - always look through the documentation first.  A quick Google search answers your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the Java tutorial, [How to Use Progress Bars](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html):

> `JProgressBar(int)`
>   `JProgressBar(int,
>   int, int)` - Create a progress bar with
>   the specified orientation, which can
>   be either `JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL` or
>   `JProgressBar.VERTICAL`. The optional
>   second and third arguments specify
>   minimum and maximum values.